# Probability that two sets are equal

Tags: probability

Let M be a set of n(M) elements. Let H be a set of n(H) elements. Let H be a subset of M. Let an element of M be chosen at random and be found to be an element of H. What is the probability that H=M?

Comment: According to which probability distribution is $H$ randomly selected as a subset of $M$?

Comment: A distribution in which each element has the same likelihood of selection.

Comment: Your notation suggests that $n(M)$ and $n(H)$ are known.  Taken together with letting "$H$ be a subset of $M$", you already have enough information to determine whether $H=M$ without resorting to a probabilistic approach.

Comment: n(M) and n(H) are variables

Comment: @PaulHalley:  The point is that $H=M$ if and only if $n(H)=n(M)$, in your notation.  If you want to construct a "probability" problem, you need to assign probabilities to your random variables.

Comment: Yep. My statement of problem was inaccurate. n(H) is unknown. H is unknown. I need to accurately define the problem. "Especially Lime" may have done so. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't well-defined at the moment. Here's one possible interpretation, and an answer, but it may not be the version you mean.

**Question:** $M$ is a fixed set, with $n$ elements. $H\subseteq M$ is chosen by letting each element of $M$ be in $H$ with probability $p$, independently of the others, for some given constant $p>0$. A randomly-chosen element of $M$ is found to be in $H$. Given this, what is the probability that $H=M$?

**Answer:** Write $A$ for the event that the random element of $M$ is in $H$, and $B$ for the event $H=M$. Now $\Pr(A)=p$, since we can choose our random element first, then we know that any given element (including the one we chose) has probability $p$ of being in $H$. $\Pr(B)=p^n$, and $\Pr(A\mid B)=1$ (if all the elements are in $H$, then any one we randomly select will be). So
$$\Pr(B\mid A)=\frac{\Pr(A\mid B)\Pr(B)}{\Pr(A)}=p^{n-1}.$$

Comment: Thank you. I agree my problem was not well defined. I'll review my question and your answer in the morning (it's 1am my time). Thanks again.

Comment: My problem is two-fold: 1. probability is not my area of expertise, 2. I have attempted (and failed) to express a real problem in abstract terms.
The real problem is this. In Australia, an investigative journalist discovered that government held records of certain citizens' data were for sale on the dark web.
He claimed that he bought his own record without problem. The government claims only 75 records were sold (hacked). The probability that only 75 records were sold and that this journalist just "happened" to be one of them is, I believe, 75/total number of citizens' records.

Comment: The question arises: What does the fact that the journalist was able to purchase his record tell us about the likelihood that any given proportion of the total citizens' records was hacked. For example, can we estimate the probability that, say, over 90% of records were hacked. How does this determination vary if two, or more (random) selections of records can be found to be available at the first attempt?